# Ribbon client not able to discover microservices registered with eureka

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

Hi I have created two microservices 1. spotparkin and 2. spotparking2 and they have successfully registered with eureka server then I created ribbon client and tried making a rest call using the application name spotpaking , which is application name that I have given in application.yml file in both microservices but I am getting below error :

> 2016-10-16 13:28:35.177 ERROR 11304 --- [nio-7213-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in c ontext with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GE T request for "http://spotparking/spotparking/pincode":
>   spotparking; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   spotparking] with root cause
>
> java.net.UnknownHostException: spotparking
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]

```
ParkingSpot parkingSpot = restTemplate.exchange("http://spotparking/spotparking/{pincode}",HttpMethod.GET,null,new ParameterizedTypeReference<ParkingSpot>() {}, pincode).getBody();
        return new MessageWrapper<>(parkingSpot, "server called using eureka with rest template");

This is how it is comming up in eureka:
```

[image]

source code is available on https://github.com/focode/microservices2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LoadBalanced was missing from ribbon
 and also added

```
client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
    lease:
      duration: 5
```

code is working now, and can be taken from my github account